# Layout does NOT disappear

Tags: android, xml, layout, fragment

In Android Studio 2.1.2, I try Basic Activity with a Fragment. Whether I see any writings, I cannot follow it. When I create a new project, it includes MainActivity.java, MainActivityFragment.java, activity_main.xml, content_main.xml and fragment_main.xml. But all writings do NOT include content_main.xml.

I try continueously and success in showing other fragment. But layout thraw. First Fragment(fragment_main.xml) dose NOT disappear. Second Fragment(fragment_sub.xml) appears in the back of first fragment.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

How can I fix it? Thank you for your concerning in advance.

These are my java sources.

```
package com.example.john.ho05fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void clickButtonNext(View view) {

        Fragment fragment = new SubActivityFragment();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace( R.id.fragment, fragment );
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void clickButtonPrevious(View view) {

        Fragment fragment = new MainActivityFragment();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace( R.id.fragment, fragment );
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}


package com.example.john.ho05fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}

package com.example.john.ho05fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class SubActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public SubActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub, container, false);
    }
}
```

These are my xml sources.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.john.ho05fragment.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.john.ho05fragment.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    tools:context="com.example.john.ho05fragment.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World! Main!!!"
        android:onClick="clickButtonNext"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_sub.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    tools:context="com.example.john.ho05fragment.SubActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World! Sub!!!!"
        android:onClick="clickButtonPrevious"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your fragment layouts are having margins from screen while your fragment of content_main is not having margins, so remove padding from both fragment layouts as below:

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF0000"
tools:context="com.example.john.ho05fragment.MainActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World! Main!!!"
    android:onClick="clickButtonNext"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_sub.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0000FF"
tools:context="com.example.john.ho05fragment.SubActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World! Sub!!!!"
    android:onClick="clickButtonPrevious"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Button appears well. But first fragment does not disappear. Second fragment is covered with first fragment. I can see only [HELLO WORLD! MAIN!!!].

Comment: Yeah because you have added fragment_main by including it in your content_main.xml